# How to Model jQuery UI Widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uml

I'm trying to model using UML the jQuery UI Widgets, its also includes Sequence Diagrams and Class Diagrams, any idea in how to do that ? or at least any existing references.

> **Edit1**: (*Thanks to @Ben Barden for the tip*)
>
> I'm trying to modify the jQuery UI Widgets in order to add OOP capabilities, the implementation job is almost done, but I have an extra requirement: to document the project using UML and OpenUp, so I need everything related with Sequence Diagram and Class Diagram of the "original" jQuery UI Widgets, or at least, know how to make those kinds of diagrams in this kind of project.

Comment: Try for a bit more clarity here.  Please make clearer what you are using, what exactly you're going for, what you've tried, what help you need, and so forth.  It sounds like you're just looking for an idea of how to get started, but from reading your question, I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to get started on, or what you hope to do it with.

Comment: @BenBarden It's done, now the question it's more descriptive.